# How do I copy aliases in my cmder without typing them like alias

Tags: cmder

How do I copy aliases in my cmder without typing them like

`$ alias e.=explorer...`
in the terminal ??  for example this

https://gist.github.com/DavidMCarek/87687a81e2574df615ed8a48299a5023

I want to copy most of these entries in a file..

Answer (score 0):

One method is to actually copy and paste these aliases into your actual aliases file.

You can do this by going to your cmder download location > config > `user-aliases.cmd`

Open your `user-aliases.cmd` file in an editor and paste all of the aliases you want to use. For example, I have a few aliases for git commands to speed up my workflow:

[image: user-aliases file for cmder]

Save the file and then restart cmder. You should be able to use your aliases now. For example, here's my `git status` alias (`gs`) now in use:

[image: git status alias in use in cmder]